# Merging Two csv files with different column lengths with R

Tags: r

I am trying to merge two files in R in an attempt to compute the correlation. One file is located at http://richardtwatson.com/data/SolarRadiationAthens.csv and the other at http://richardtwatson.com/data/electricityprices.csv

Currently my code looks as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
data1<-read.csv("C:/Users/nldru/Downloads/SolarRadiationAthens.csv")
data2 <- read.csv("C:/Users/nldru/Downloads/electricityprices.csv")
n <- merge(data1,data2)
```

I have the code stored locally on my computer just for ease of access. The files are being read in properly, but for some reason when I merge, variable n receives no data, just the headers of the columns from the csv files. I have experimented with using inner_join to no avail as well as pulling the files directly from the http address linked above and using read_delim() commands but can't seem to get it to work. Any help or tips are much appreciated.

Comment: If you are trying to merge by timestamp, the two timestamp columns of your dataframes are different: one is capitalized and one isn't. Rename the `data1` column by doing `colnames(data1)[1] = "timestamp"` and then try to merge.

Comment: The column names are different between files, one is "Time Stamp" the other is "timestamp".  Try `merge(data1, data2, by.x = "Time Stamp", by.y = "timestamp")`

Comment: Thanks for the help! The merge was successful.